# Change the background of DropDownList Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, background, disable

I have a DropDownList Combobox that will be enable and disable base on user input. But I want to customize the background of an DISABLED combo.
Try set background color doesnt work for me. Is it possible to change or the disabled control will be control by framework.

Comment: Override `OnDrawItem`. `e.DrawBackground();` will paint the background with the selected BackColor even when the Combo is disabled.

Comment: @Jimi My bad, sorry..

Answer (score 0):

It is not designed by default. But you can redraw the combobox. Use this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15078/A-Combobox-that-Looks-Decent-When-it-is-Disabled) as a reference